# Lua Calling a function using its name(string)

Tags: function, oop, lua

I am trying to call a function by its name but, because the function I am trying to call is a method, all args I am trying to get are nil. How should I be able to call this function with all the args?

Here's a little example of what I am trying to do:

```
local s = "hi"    
local test = {}

function test:hi(n)
    print(n)
end

test[s]("hello")
```

print    --> nil

Comment: Hint: what is the difference between `function test.hi(n) ... end` and `function test:hi(n) ... end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
function test:hi(n)
  print(n)
end
```

Is the exact equivalent of this:

```
function test.hi(self, n)
  print(n)
end
```

So you can get the result you are looking for by doing this:

```
test[s](test, "hello")
```

Or seeing as the `test` argument is not used, you could also call it like this:

```
test[s](nil, "hello")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not `function test.hi(test, n)` but `function test.hi(self, n)`

Comment: Ah, right you are, sorry about that. I fixed the answer.